# Facebook Graph request Android name from user ID

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm trying to get the name of a user from his user ID. 
on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761576/android-get-facebook-user-name-from-their-id-number) link they say that we can do it from a simple HTTP request like that:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/4
```

But it seems that this method is outdated because i cant get anything because:

```
"An access token is requir…o request this resource."
```

Anyway i tried using their documentation about the graph api on Android and i did it like that:

```
    GraphRequestAsyncTask request1 = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/"+id1+"/name",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,

        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                /* handle the result */
            }
        }
    ).executeAsync();
    name1.setText(request1.toString());
```

But on the `name1` TextView i get a message that tells me

```
{RequestAsyncTask:
    connection:null,requests:[{Request:
    accesToken:{AccessToken
        token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:
        [public_profile]},
        graphPath:/100017723671435/name, graphObject: null,
        httpMethod:Get,
        parameters:Bundle[{}]}]}
```

I don't really understand how to do, i have a bunch of facebook ID's on my database and i just want to get the name from the ID, to display it on the screen.

The current user of the app is not the profile which i want to get the infos!

EDIT: It seems i misunderstood the `/*handle the result*/` commentary, i made this line like that:

```
name1.setText(response.toString());
```

But i have still an error on my TextView:

```
{Response: 
    responseCode:400,
    graphObject:null,
    error: { HttpStatus:400,
             errorCode: 2500,
             errorType: OAuthException,
             errorMessage: Unknown path components: /first_name }}
```

So it seems i don't use the Graph Paths properly. I'm still looking on the doc and on Google, if i find the answer i'll give the code!

Comment: `first_name` is a field not an edge. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are logged in with read permission.
If you are logged in you can try with:

```
GraphRequest.Callback gCallback = new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: ");
            if (response != null && response.getJSONObject() != null && response.getJSONObject().has("first_name"))
            {
                try {
                    name1.setText(response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCompleted: ",e );
                }
            }
        }
    };
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),"/me?fields=id,name,gender,email,first_name,last_name", null,HttpMethod.GET, gCallback).executeAsync();
```

If you have a problem with login, maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634660/facebook-sdk-4-0-1-login-without-login-button) can help you.

Comment: Okay thanks that works now! I don't really understand the graph doc so thanks for explaining me like that :D